# home vs cloud security

Tags: cloud-computing

I recommended to a friend that code would be better off stored in the cloud in Google or Amazon or some other big cloud provider than in one's home due to Google and/or Amazon having arguably the best coders/personnel in the world securing their infrastructure.  My friend has secured their home network but I told them that a home network/server could not compare in anyway to what Google or Amazon provides from a security perspective seeing that they have extremely talented people ensuring their infrastructure is secure.

I (as a web developer) have recommended to many IT oriented friends that I have talked with to move things into the cloud for the security and redundancy that is the combination of multitudes of engineers working on.  One person attempting to secure their home network just can't compare to the talent that big vendors like Google and Amazon have.

Ultimately, am I right to state that one person securing a home network/server can't compare to the world's best engineers securing infrastructures in huge companies like Google and Amazon?

Comment: While I think this is an interesting question for discussion, I think it's also out of scope for this site as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Related question: Are you planning on moving into a Google datacenter to do your work?  If not, what are you doing to secure the code while it is checked out on your PC?

Comment: @CortAmmon Good question/consideration.  One could move source code to the cloud but read/write it from an insecure PC and compromise it that way.

Comment: Hackers always take [the easy way](https://xkcd.com/538/). =)

Comment: `that they have extremely talented people ensuring their infrastructure is secure.` ... from DVD copies, Chinese companies doing uninterrupted business, people who don't want total surveillance, and several other things? Sure, and the nice NSA is helping them. lol ... And if this isn't enough, *cost*. Answer to your last sentence, absolutely not.

Comment: ...an argument that you might agree more with: Did you ever see a company where the best security person / programmer / whatever can use his/her ability to the fullest, without being blocked from all sites? If it is not because of cost, it is eg. that the less gifted employees should understand it too, or some random intern not being careful with his password despite there being enough rules to prevent that, and so on. That's especially true for big companies like Google. ... I as computer owner at home can rely on myself much more than on the weakset link of a 70K people blob.

Comment: @deviantfan I appreciate your comments.  I have not heard of the things you've mentioned about Google.  You have certainly caused me to fret about them from a security perspective.  Are there references to those events?  I would certainly upvote your 1st comment if it were put as an answer with references of those events you mentioned.

Comment: @ZackMacomber If I had enough detail evidence for a good answer, the world could be a better place ... anyways, about the three mentioned things ... if it is not known, a "national security letter" is a unfunny legal thing in the US containing surveillance orders to companies, without the right to tell anyone. There are very few cases where the company managed to get a publishing permission in an secret (lol) court. These seldom cases are eg. 19 times for Google (https://techcrunch.com/2016/12/13/google-national-security-letters/ and many more). ...

Comment: The published ones contain eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Snowden And the documents that he brought to light also contain large-scale industry espionage actions by NSA&co ......... completely independent of Google inner workings, I don't think any US company can be trusted in the current state of this country. NSLs, secret courts, Guantanamo, assassinations, ...